# Symfony getRepository not working in tests with ServiceEntityRepositories

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, repository

I want to enable easy autowiring for my Repositories. At the same time I need to be able to switch DB connections on them (so define them in services.yaml with different db conn)

I extend all my Repos from a BaseRepository which implements `ServiceEntityRepositoryInterface` and extends `EntityRepository`

The constructor looks like this:

```
public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry, $entityClass, $connection = "default")
{
    $manager = $registry->getManager($connection);

    parent::__construct($manager, $manager->getClassMetadata($entityClass));
}
```

Now the constructor of most of my Repositories themselves look like this:

```
public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
{
    parent::__construct($registry, MyEntity::class);
}
```

Some have an extra `$connection` argument to allow overwriting their connection. Since sometimes I need repos accessing different databases.

This works perfectly in my frontend and gets just autowired without even defining anything besides a generic loading of all services/repositories in the services.yaml

In Tests I want to get these repos aswell.

I do this, in a base test class

```
$this->em = $this->bootedKernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```

In my test then I want to do

```
$this->myRepo = $this->em->getRepository(MyEntity::class);
```

This horribly fails with

```
RuntimeException: The "\Moebel\MyApp\Repository\MyEntityRepository" entity repository implements "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepositoryInterface", but its service could not be found. Make sure the service exists and is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service
```

I have tried tagging the repositories in the services.yaml but it made no difference. I looked through some of the symfonfy code and saw this:
(in `ContainerRepositoryFactory`)

```
return $this->managedRepositories[$repositoryHash] = new $repositoryClassName($entityManager, $metadata);
```

I don't read symfony code a lot but this looks like to me the code that getRepository uses calls my class with an entityManager which is wrong for me. I want the ManagerRegistry.

What's the best way to fix my issues with Doctrine and Repositories?

**Edit:** I found a solution, but not for all Problems.
Directly using the container and not letting doctrine fetch the repo so like this:

```
self::$container->get(MyEntityRepository::class);
```

Maybe anyone has a better idea? Because now I can't get Repos with different connections, or I'm unsure how.

Comment: Can you read the Doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html. I think this will help you inderstand

Comment: @YoussefSaoubou I've read that. But it's terrible code IMO. Doing $this->getDoctrine etc. in a Controller is ugly, your controller doesn't depend on the entirety of doctrine etc. just on a Repository. My Controllers are dependency injected with the Repositories they need. And that is the thing the docs don't explain.

Comment: I confess I don't quite follow what you trying to do.  You cannot change the database connection on a per repository basis.  Each connection will require it's own entity manager and you then grab the repository from it.  The ServiceEntityRepositoryInterface does not really work well here because it simply looks through all available entity managers and picks the first one that supports the given entity.

Comment: I think you need to define your own repository services to specify which entity manager they use and thus which connection.  Here is a [somewhat dated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672519/injecting-repositories-into-factory-symfony2/29674138#29674138).  But what really confuses me about your question is that your $em->getRepository($entityClass) should have worked.  The fact that you seem to be getting a container error is bizarre since doctrine itself knows nothing about services.  I think you have something complete different going on.

Comment: @Cerad Doctrine do getRepositories with a ManagerRegistry somehow, which is what i require and which is what the ServiceEntityRepositoryInterface wants. So it doesn't know about Services and yea it doesn't need to.

Comment: Which is exactly my point.  The error message ...but its service could not be found. Make sure the service exists and is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service"... Is coming from the container.  Bizarre.

Comment: @Cerad Although the "ContainerRepositoryFactory" does know about services and it's the one responsible for creating the repo. https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Repository/ContainerRepositoryFactory.php

Comment: Well that is new.  Wonder how they deal with public vs private services.  Maybe it really gets a service locator instead of the full container.  If you don't implement the interface then you would be okay.  If I get bored maybe I'll try to dup.  Might be useful to create a new project with one repository showing the issue and then checking everything in.  I'd be willing to check it out and see what is happening.